# MongoDB - How to convert string to date and perform a filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

[image]

How do I convert the field date of type `String` to `Date` before doing a filter to get all dates greater than the current date? Thanks!

Comment: Give some test data and expected result would be better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)  - Convert date string to `Date`.
2. [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW) - Variable to get current datetime.
3. [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/) - Allow aggregration expression within the query language.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $toDate: "$date"
      },
      "$$NOW"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeMU3913_YA)

Answer (score 1):

data

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    item: "apple",
    qty: 5,
    order_date: new Date("2018-03-10")
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    item: "pie",
    qty: 10,
    order_date: new Date("2018-03-12")
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    item: "ice cream",
    qty: 2,
    price: "4.99",
    order_date: "2018-03-05"
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    item: "almonds",
    qty: 5,
    price: 5,
    order_date: "2018-03-05 +10:00"
  }
]
```

`$toDate`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      convertedDate: {
        $toDate: "$order_date"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/krjFcSkwc41)